# d3 js rollup group by alphabet

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have below a json data to draw multiple rectangles in a graph

```
data.push(["Shanghai","Los Angeles","33333333.33"]);
data.push(["Los Angeles","Shanghai","222222.33"]);

data.push(["Los Angeles","Shanghai","22.33"]);
data.push(["chennai","Bombay","33333333.33"]);

data.push(["Canada","Japan","33333333.33"]);
data.push(["Japan","Canada","222222.33"]);

data.push(["Bombay","Canada","222222222.33"]);
data.push(["Bombay","Belgaum","222222.33"]);
data.push(["Bombay","Delhi","222222.33"]);
```

How above data can be grouped based on the first character data like group by B, C etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `d3.nest()`

```
var d = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { 
      return d[0].charAt(0); // 1st char of the 1st item of the array
   })
  .entries(data);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/rc32kdxn/